# addChild tells root.gotoAndStop();

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How do you tell the root timeline to `root.gotoAndStop(2);` from the timeline of a movieClip added using addChild?

In the maintime line I have

```
addChild(fade_eng);
```

and in fade_eng 
I have the following on frame 20

```
root.gotoAndStop(2);
this.gotoAndStop(1);
```

But I am getting 1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typecast `root` to `MovieClip`.

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(1);
```

[This thread](http://www.kongregate.com/forums/4/topics/3935) should thoroughly explain the process and how it works.

Comment: Yep just figured that out. If I continue to Typecast root as a MovieClip from other child MovieClips will that hurt performance for any reason?

Comment: @Denoteone — There shouldn't be performance problems and if there are, just keep a reference to the casted MovieClip somewhere. However the architecture of your app is flawed based on principles of OOP: lower hierarchical objects should not be able to change states of higher objects in hierarchy. You should instead define your own 'entry-point' class and add that to root (main Stage) and then rely on event model (dispatching events from child MC's) to stop or pause your 'entry-point' class.

Comment: @joncys I agree complete. this issue came about as I was testing something (not for production) and when I noticed I couldn't control the main timeline I was just curios why. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: There's no need to put the time into a model as described unless you either already have a framework lying around or the project is going to be a decent size / worked on over a long period.

Comment: ... Hmm? You can cast with Class()? Wow, I learned something new, thank you!

Comment: Note that it's bad architecture to even try to control parents from their children.  Instead, children should dispatch events that the parent should catch and react to.

Comment: @Amy I'm not disagreeing at all - there's just situations like mine where being in a work environment that is volume heavy I don't have time to implement this on each project I work on. Most of the time I get allocated about 45-90 minutes for smaller projects. I of course include a nicer structure in personal or larger projects :)